# Does Animate Rope remove magical properties of a magic rope?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, magic-items

[Animate rope](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/animate-rope) can be used on a magical rope like an [Iron Rope](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/h-l/iron-rope/) or a [Rope of Knots](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/r-z/rope-of-knots/) - that's pretty clear. It just has to be a "nonliving rope-like object." A Rope of Knots is not living. But if we look down at the end of the spell, it says something disturbing.

> The rope itself and any knots tied in it are not magical.

This is clearly to explain that if you tie a knot with the rope, it's not a magic unbreakable knot or something. But will it remove the magic of my [Rope of Climbing](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/r-z/rope-of-climbing)? Will that be temporary or permanent? Does this invalidate casting the spell on my enemy's Rope of Climbing? I think not, since it states not that the spell can't be cast on a magical rope, but that the rope *is not magical.*

For that matter, will the rope register as magical to [Detect Magic](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/detect-magic/) if it was not magical before? Will it register as magical to Detect Magic if it was magical before?

Yes, I am aware that this was almost certainly unintended even if it technically works - Animate Rope is not Disenchant Rope. I don't want an answer that says only "Yeah, but no sane DM would accept that." I want to know what technically happens, and then never use that knowledge.

Comment: Help Center states that [You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). If you don't want to use that knowledge, then it seems that you are not facing any actual problem.

Comment: @Mołot do you want to delete half of [tag:optimization] then?

Comment: @Ekadh Most of the optimization questions are asking for knowledge that is useful, and will be used. Usually not as a direct copy of hypervoptimized solutions, but still.

Answer (score 1):

The wording of Animate Rope highlighted in your question is pretty ambiguous, however it seems like the intended meaning of the phrase is that the spell does not have any effect on magical properties (or lack thereof) of the targeted rope, it just lets you manipulate it.

Answer (score 1):

#### Ambiguous, DM may need to define, but intuition may be enough to convince.

Following the links provided, the description for the spell includes the following:

> You can animate a nonliving rope-like object.

There are considerations of thickness and length of rope, but material and magical content are absent.

This magically animates the rope and allows you to give the commands listed in the description with a note: (Emphasis mine)

> You can give one command each round as a move action, **as if directing an active spell**.

It then describes various scenarios where the rope can be used:

> The rope can enwrap only a creature or an object within 1 foot of it –
> it does not snake outward – so it must be thrown near the intended
> target.

At the end of which it notes:

> The rope **itself and any knots tied in it are not magical**.

Which seems intentional to designate for resistances or other effects that might affect magical items, that the rope itself is under a magical effect, rather than having become magic in itself due to that effect. The magic produced the knots, but they are not magical knots. Casting dispel magic will not untie the knots, but end the magic that is affecting the rope allowing it to become knotted and unknotted via verbal command.

Again, this is ambiguous, but I would not assume that to mean that it would make an otherwise magic rope, no-longer magic. It's simply magic in this case but not because of the spell.

Poor wording unfortunately.